# How to split a list of strings into given number of lists in erlang

Tags: erlang

Given a list and an integer, I want to split that list into the specified number of lists (inside a list).

For example:

Input:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

What is a clean and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31396957/49197) written by [Steve Vinoski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409228/steve-vinoski) calls `length/1` in guard for each partition which makes it `O(N^2)`. It simply bothers me because it can be done in `O(N)` and I am performance freak. It can be done in many ways so just for example there is one:

```
divide(L, N) when is_integer(N), N > 0 ->
    divide(N, 0, L, []).

divide(_, _, [], Acc) ->
    [lists:reverse(Acc)];
divide(N, N, L, Acc) ->
    [lists:reverse(Acc) | divide(N, 0, L, [])];
divide(N, X, [H|T], Acc) ->
    divide(N, X+1, T, [H|Acc]).
```

or as a modification of Steve's solution

```
divide(L, N) ->
    divide(L, N, []).

divide([], _, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
divide(L, N, Acc) ->
    try lists:split(N, L) of
        {H,T} -> divide(T, N, [H|Acc])
    catch
        error:badarg ->
            lists:reverse([L|Acc])
    end.
```

or even simpler:

```
divide([], _) -> [];
divide(L, N) ->
    try lists:split(N, L) of
        {H,T} -> [H|divide(T, N)]
    catch
        error:badarg -> [L]
    end.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lists:split/2` for this:

```
divide(L, N) ->
    divide(L, N, []).
divide([], _, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
divide(L, N, Acc) when length(L) < N ->
    lists:reverse([L|Acc]);
divide(L, N, Acc) ->
    {H,T} = lists:split(N, L),
    divide(T, N, [H|Acc]).
```

The first function, `divide/2`, serves as the entry point. It merely calls the helper function `divide/3` with an initial accumulator value of an empty list, and then `divide/3` does all the work. The first clause of `divide/3` matches when the list has been completely processed, so it just reverses the accumulator and returns that value. The second clause handles the case when the length of `L` is less than the requested `N` value; it creates a new accumulator by prepending `Acc` with `L` and then returning the reverse of that new accumulator. The third clause first calls `lists:split/2` to split the incoming list into `H`, which is a list of `N` elements, and `T`, the remainder of the list. It then calls itself recursively, passing `T` as the new list value, the original `N` value, and a new accumulator consisting of `H` as the first element and the original accumulator, `Acc`, as the tail.